# Using CSS with Bootstrap will not work no matter what I try

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap libraries to create my website and I want to use CSS to modify parts of the pare layout like the background color and the color of the jumbotron but nothing will make that work. 
How do I apply CSS to work alongside with bootstrap.

```
.jumbotron 
    {
        background-color:red !important; 
    }

    #body
    {
        background-color:black;
    }
```

```
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <p>"Quote goes here"</p>
        <h1>Site name</h1>
        <p>Motto and slogan goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: you wrongly used you body selector

Comment: no element in your code has the `#body` value as the `id` attribue

Comment: http://jsbin.com/soxazopeya/1/edit?html,css,output — Seems to work. You need a [MCVE]

Comment: Make sure your own styles are loading after the bootstrap otherwise bootstrap will override your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you wrap you css in the style tag?

```
<style type="text/css">
 .jumbotron 
    {
        background-color:red !important; 
    }

body
    {
        background-color:black;
    }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <p>"Quote goes here"</p>
        <h1>Site name</h1>
        <p>Motto and slogan goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: results]

Comment: I am using external CSS file, now i got the jumbotron working as I want it to however the background color still doesnt work, now I tried to internal CSS like yours and external CSS and the background stays transparent(white)

Comment: you should use the body selector, not the #body selector. if it not works key F12 in you chrome browser and see the style cascade info.